# How to select data from mysql database correctly ? ResultSet error

Tags: java, mysql

I'm working on a project and I have some issues with printing the selected data from database.
This is the mysql connection :

```
import java.sql.*;

public class MysqlConnect {

    public Connection conn = null;
    public String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    public String dbName = "jdbctutorial";
    public String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    public String userName = "birthday";
    public String password = "123456";
    public Statement stmt = null;
    public String query = "";
    public int rs = 0;
    public PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    public ResultSet rrs = null;

    public void crearedatabase() {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
            // System.out.println("Connected to the database");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Baza de date nu a fost creata");
        }

    }

    public void executareSql() {
        try {
            rs = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Eroare sql");
        }
    }

    public void executaresSqlPrepareSt(String nume, String prenume, int ziua, int luna, int an) {
        try {
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO persoane(Nume,Prenume,Ziua,Luna,An)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);");

            pstmt.setString(1, nume);
            pstmt.setString(2, prenume);
            pstmt.setInt(3, ziua);
            pstmt.setInt(4, luna);
            pstmt.setInt(5, an);
            pstmt.execute();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Eroare prepareSql.");
        }
    }

    public void selectsql() {
        try {
            rrs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }

    public void returnareRezultat() throws SQLException {
        while (rrs.next()) {
            String nume = rrs.getString("FirstName");
            String prenume = rrs.getString("LastName");
            int ziua = rrs.getInt("Day");
            int luna = rrs.getInt("Month");
            int an = rrs.getInt("Year");

            // print the results
            System.out.format("%s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n", nume, prenume, ziua, luna, an);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the part where I call the method from my GUI:

```
........................
```

int zi_actuala = data_azi.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int luna_actuala = data_azi.get(Calendar.MONTH);

```
    mysql.query = "SELECT Nume ,Prenume,Ziua,Luna,An FROM persoane WHERE (Ziua="+zi_actuala+" AND Luna="+luna_actuala+"); ";
    mysql.selectsql();
```

.................

My error is on `rrs = stmt.executeQuery(query);`(java.lang.NullPointerException)

This is the full error `at MysqlConnect.selectsql(MysqlConnect.java:63)
    at GuiApp.<init>(GuiApp.java:120)
    at GuiApp$1.run(GuiApp.java:55)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)`

Can you help me ? thanks in advance.

Comment: mysql.query = "SELECT Nume ,Prenume,Ziua,Luna,An FROM persoane WHERE (Ziua="+zi_actuala+" AND Luna="+luna_actuala+"); ";

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException, maybe because you haven't called crearedatabase(), so the stmt is null.

Comment: i call the crearedatabase method

Answer (score 0):

do like this.

```
    mysql.query = "SELECT Nume ,Prenume,Ziua,Luna,An FROM persoane WHERE (Ziua="+zi_actuala+" AND Luna="+luna_actuala+"); ";
    mysql.crearedatabase();
    mysql.selectsql();
```

Comment: thanks it's working ...I called the function ,but i called on other funtions...My mistake.Thank you guys very much  for your time!